# Practicas adecuadas para MVC (Html, css y js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mvc

Alguien seria tan amable de explicarme como puedo ordenar las carpetas segun el MVC si deseo usar (Html, Css y js). Lo que necesito saber es cuales archivos van en cada carpeta siguiendo buenas practicas.

Ej. Dentro de la carpeta vistas, deben ir todos los archivos css.

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: pregunto; vas a usar un framework? por que dependiendo el framework cambia el orden de carpetas, si estás indeciso te recomiendo laravel 9

Comment: @Osaskoh No usare un Framework, sera solamente html, css y js. Solo la parte front end.

Comment: @Osaskoh, Creo que no es necesario saber que framework o lenguaje utiliza, porque MVC es un patrón de diseño que excede el lenguaje utilizado.

Comment: Se ve mejor tener las carpetas en inglés (controller, views...) a mi punto de vista. Al usar este patrón de diseño (en distintos lenguajes), el orden de las carpetas lo tienen mayormente así: Models (lógica con bd), Views (html, css, js), Controller (funciones de la vista).

Comment: @Cris223511.dev A que te refieres con "Fuentes de la vista" ?

Comment: Funciones* ya hay una respuesta que te lo explica mejor.

Comment: No preguntes por buenas prácticas en [es.so] ya que estas preguntas tienden a ser muy amplias y/o basadas en opiniones. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un [ejemplo](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/miguelmota/7728274/raw/34fda58dfa6ae3258502a0d7037b09f9cf591951/nodejs-directory-structure.md) de estructura de un proyecto MVC en **NodeJS** y [**Jade**](https://jade-lang.com)

**Modelo**:
Como su nombre lo indica, un modelo es un diseño o estructura . En el caso de MVC, el modelo determina cómo se estructura una base de datos, definiendo una sección de la aplicación que interactúa con la base de datos. Aquí es donde definiremos las propiedades de un usuario que se almacenarán en nuestra base de datos.

**Vista**:
La vista es donde los usuarios finales interactúan dentro de la aplicación. En pocas palabras, aquí es donde van todos los archivos de plantilla HTML.

**Controlador**:
El controlador interactúa con el modelo y sirve la respuesta y la funcionalidad a la vista. Cuando un usuario final realiza una solicitud, se envía al controlador que interactúa con la base de datos.

[Fuente](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-structuring-node-js-mvc-application/)